# 12 and 13-bit balanced Gray codes

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am trying to find a transition sequence for both 12 and 13 bit balanced Gray codes. I know there are some excellent papers on the topic of deriving these sequences available on the internet, but I regret to say that it's been a while since I've been in a formal math class and I can't quite follow them to the end.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-Erik

Comment: May I point you to http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatquestions - there doesn't seem to be a question here other than 'help me understand this vague thing'. If you ask about specific sticking points (and at least show what you do know) then you will attract more answers.

Comment: That faq will also point you to some sites that may be better suited for this question

Comment: You mean binary Gray code?  There is a construction in the Wikipedia article for Gray codes.